# moving a file to another server

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server

Is it possible to copy a file from flash media server to a web server? I can forsee if it is on the same server then it is possible via php but what if it is on two separate servers?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the server. There are some, that support Flash media streaming, like [Red5](http://www.osflash.org/red5).

I didn't use them much, but it's a hassle, most of the time. If you want to move the file itself, you'd best doing it with the file itself, with your PHP program.

You might as well use other tools, like `scp` or `rsync`, in case you're not against using external tools (this depends on your OS, of course.